# How to use calcBackProject in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tracking, mean-shift

What's the meaning of the first and fourth parameters?

[image]Can I cut an Image into 9 pieces and then use it's histgram as the parameter hist in the picture and the whole image as the first parameter in the picture?